# Responsive template alignment

Tags: responsive-design

I am developing a website by downloading some template from net.
I modified some width and height according to our requirement the output is fine in PC but when I check it in mobile the contents are overflowing against background.

Please help me with some solution to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you change height and width in `px` then you have to set it accordingly in every `media screen` using `@media`...for responsive site its better to use dimensions  in `%` rather than `px`

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider below dimensions then you have to write accordingly in every media screen using @media queries.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
```